# How to do kerberos authentication in Node js

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, authentication, sequelize.js, kerberos

I'm changing my NTLM authentication to kerberos authentication in my node js code. But I'm not able to find any reference to add kerberos configuration and I'm using sequelize ORM. Do I have to change it to any other ORM in order to add kerberos configuration?

I have already referred this page https://www.npmjs.com/package/kerberos but I don't have miniconda 2.7 and python 2.7. please suggest me how to proceed with this python 3.7 version. I want to know the steps to install kerberos file in my machine and do the configuration to make it work.

Comment: Try to use krb5 module

Comment: I have tried that but not able to execute this command 
choco install mitkerberos --install-arguments="ADDLOCAL=all"
npm install krb5